# SAP UI5 Smart Table Json Data Usage

Tags: sapui5

I've got a problem about usage of json data in smart table object. I'm getting json data from web service and I set that json data any other variable. How can I bind that variable to EntitySet ? In fact I haven't got any json file in my application folders.

Here is the application sample link that I used for my project;
https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.tutorial.walkthrough.27/code

Here is the my metadata.xml codes;

```
<edmx:Edmx Version="1.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx">
<edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="1.0" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="3.0"
                   xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <Schema Namespace="UserModel" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm">
        <EntityType Name="Users">
            <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="TKID"/>
                <PropertyRef Name="TKTX"/>
            </Key>
            <Property Name="TKTX" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="40" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true"/>
            <Property Name="TKID" Type="Edm.Int16" Nullable="false"/>           
        </EntityType>
    </Schema>
    <Schema Namespace="ODataWebV2.Northwind.Model" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm">
        <EntityContainer Name="UserModelEntities" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true" p6:LazyLoadingEnabled="true"
                         xmlns:p6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation">
            <EntitySet Name="Users" EntityType="UserModel.Users"/>
    <!--How can I bind my json data incoming from webservice ?-->
        </EntityContainer>
    </Schema>
</edmx:DataServices>
```

[image: Here is the my json data result;]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can populate an entity in an Odatamodel using its createEntry method. It is not a very usual (read recommended) scenario to pull the metadata of an odataservice from one endpoint and data from another. It would be good to provide a bit of insight in why you are trying to do it this way.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, I want to bind datas coming from web service without using metadata.xml file. In sap examples had been used metadata file. But there is no metadata file in my application. As you can see above the image the data is coming json data format type. Therefore I can not set that data to EntitySet. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Ah, I see. If you're getting your data from a JSON service, wouldn't it then make more sense to use the JSONModel instead of the ODataModel and bind your Table control to that?